# Find the missing coordinate of rectangle

Tags: algorithm, c++11

Chef has N axis-parallel rectangles in a 2D Cartesian coordinate system. These rectangles may intersect, but it is guaranteed that all their 4N vertices are pairwise distinct.

Unfortunately, Chef lost one vertex, and up until now, none of his fixes have worked (although putting an image of a point on a milk carton might not have been the greatest idea after all…). Therefore, he gave you the task of finding it! You are given the remaining 4N−1 points and you should find the missing one.

Input
The first line of the input contains a single integer T denoting the number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows.
The first line of each test case contains a single integer N.
Then, 4N−1 lines follow. Each of these lines contains two space-separated integers x and y denoting a vertex (x,y) of some rectangle.
Output
For each test case, print a single line containing two space-separated integers X and Y ― the coordinates of the missing point. It can be proved that the missing point can be determined uniquely.

Constraints
T≤100
1≤N≤2⋅105
|x|,|y|≤109
the sum of N over all test cases does not exceed 2⋅105
Example Input
1
2
1 1
1 2
4 6
2 1
9 6
9 3
4 3
Example Output
2 2

Problem link: https://www.codechef.com/problems/PTMSSNG

my approach: I have created a frequency array for x and y coordinates and then calculated the point which is coming odd no. of times.

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        long int n;
        cin>>n;
        long long int a[4*n-1][2];
        long long int xm,ym,x,y;
        for(int i=0;i<4*n-1;i++)
        {
            cin>>a[i][0]>>a[i][1];
            if(i==0)
            {
                xm=abs(a[i][0]);
                ym=abs(a[i][1]);
            }
            if(i>0)
            {
                if(abs(a[i][0])>xm)
                {
                    xm=abs(a[i][0]);
                }
                if(abs(a[i][1])>ym)
                {
                    ym=abs(a[i][1]);
                }
            }
        }
        long long int frqx[xm+1],frqy[ym+1];
        for(long long int i=0;i<xm+1;i++)
        {
            frqx[i]=0;
        }
        for(long long int j=0;j<ym+1;j++)
        {
            frqy[j]=0;
        }
        for(long long int i=0;i<4*n-1;i++)
        {
            frqx[a[i][0]]+=1;
            frqy[a[i][1]]+=1;
        }
        for(long long int i=0;i<xm+1;i++)
        {
            if(frqx[i]>0 && frqx[i]%2>0)
            {
                x=i;
                break;
            }
        }
        for(long long int j=0;j<ym+1;j++)
        {
            if(frqy[j]>0 && frqy[j]%2>0)
            {
                y=j;
                break;
            }
        }
        cout<<x<<" "<<y<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My code is showing TLE for inputs <10^6

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: https://www.codechef.com/problems/PTMSSNG

Comment: On this website (and quite often in life), if you need help, you'll need to make it easy for others to help you. Most people just won't bother reading external links etc. It appears your code doesn't do what you expect it to do. Is the algorithm correct (does it "work on paper"?), and if yes, have you tried using a debugger, to see when code and your assumptions don't match up?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your solution is not handling negative x/y correctly. `long long int frqx[xm+1],frqy[ym+1]` allocated barely enough memory to hold positive values, but not enough to hold negative ones.

It doesn't even matter though, as with the guarantee that `abs(x) <= 109`, you can just statically allocate a vector of `219` elements, and map both positive and negative coordinates in there.

---

Second, you are not supposed to buffer the input in `a`. Not only is this going to ***overflow the stack***, is also entirely unnecessary. Write to the frequency buckets right away, don't buffer.

Same goes for most of these challenges. Don't buffer, always try to process the input directly.

---

About your buckets, you don't need a `long long int`. A `bool` per bucket is enough. You do not care even the least how many coordinates were sorted into the bucket, only whether the number so far was even or not. What you implemented as a separate loop can be substituted by simply toggling a flag while processing the input.

Answer (score 1):

I find the answer of @Ext3h with respect to the errors adequate.

The solution, *giving that you came on the odd/even quality of the problem*,
can be done more straight-forward.

You need to find the x and y that appear an odd number of times.

In java

```
int[] missingPoint(int[][] a) {
    //int n = (a.length + 1) / 4;

    int[] pt = new int[2]; // In C initialize with 0.
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
            pt[j] ^= a[i][j];
        }
    }
    return pt; 
}
```

This uses exclusive-or `^` which is associative and reflexive 0^x=x, x^x=0. (5^7^4^7^5=4.)
For these "search the odd one" one can use this xor-ing.

In effect you do not need to keep the input in an array.